# Как получить путь к файлу имея только первые символы его названия?

Tags: python

есть файл ssfn54354564649749, каждый раз его цифры после ssfn меняются, как можно получать путь к файлу только по первым символам его названия?

Answer (score 2):

При помощи стандартного модуля glob

```
import glob
glob.glob('file/ssfn*') #в параметре передаётся синтаксис регулярных выражений, результат ввиде списка
#['file\\ssfna', 'file\\ssfn0', 'file\\ssfn.txt']
```